# Password-less SSH not working with Mac OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac, ssh

I cannot get password-less logins working on my Mac OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks machine. I can login to a remote Ubuntu box after setting up the `authorized_keys` file properly. However, I cannot do there reverse.

So I tried to troubleshoot the Mac setup by figuring out if I can do this without a password:

```
ssh localhost
```

Doing that on my Ubuntu box works well, but the Mac keeps asking for passwords. Yes I checked the `authorized_keys` file as well as the `known_hosts` file and made sure the `id_rsa.pub` key was present in both of them for my Mac. But I cannot SSH to `localhost` without a password.

I read the other posts [such as this one](https://superuser.com/questions/578427/passwordless-ssh-not-working-between-machines).

And even enabled the following two settings(by deleting the hashtag in front of them) in the `sshd_config` file:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubKeyAuthentication yes
```

Still getting asked for the password.

Put copies of the `authorized_key` and `known_hosts` files in the etc directory.

Still getting asked for the password.

Comment: maybe try stopping and starting the sshd service if you haven't already

Answer (score 7):

I provided an [answer on Stack Overflow that explains the step-by-step process needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692251/password-less-login-for-ssh-via-ssh/14692310#14692310) to set up password-less access via SSH. Here are those instructions adapted for your specific needs.

First, set the SSH connection into verbose mode by using the `-v` flag like this:

```
ssh -v localhost
```

As explained in the `ssh` man page; accessible via `man ssh`:

```
 -v      Verbose mode.  Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its
         progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentica-
         tion, and configuration problems.  Multiple -v options increase
         the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.
```

This has saved me a lot of headaches in the past by showing me exactly how the login process is flowing & what exactly is clogging it up. For example, here is the output of me running that command on my local Mac OS X 10.9.5 machine:

```
ssh -v localhost

OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Giacomo1968/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/Giacomo1968/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Giacomo1968/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Giacomo1968/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 01:aa:8e:8e:b9:e1:4b:e8:bd:c5:a2:20:a3:c7:f1:18
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Giacomo1968/.ssh/known_hosts:43
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Giacomo1968/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Giacomo1968/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

As you can see, it gets up the password prompt. But prior to that it is clearly checking for my RSA public key. And since I don’t have one, it just rolls over to the next authentication method. Pay attention to the output of `ssh -v` when you run it on your set to see where things get choked.

Also be sure the SSH files on the destination machine have permissions that match the following & are owned by the account trying to access like this example shows:

```
-rw------- [username] [usergroup] authorized_keys
-rw------- [username] [usergroup] id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- [username] [usergroup] id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- [username] [usergroup] known_hosts
```

So run this command to `chmod` the `authorized_keys` file:

```
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And run this command to `chmod` the `id_rsa` file:

```
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: 90% of the time it is permissions.

Comment: thank you for a thorough answer but i am still flummoxed. my ssh -v output is the same as yours (except for obvious differences like machine name and ssh key). Even though I do have an rsa private and public key pair and i successfully entered them into 'authorized_keys'. I also even did this: <br> ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa</br> <br>cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'</br> but i still get the password prompt. next i'll just delete the account and start over.

Comment: I deleted all my keys from .ssh folder and started over. SAME PROBLEM exists.

Comment: I created a new account and now everything works. The only thing I did differently was to use a long password when creating the account (>3 letters. I used a short password initially because this was just a 'test' account)

Comment: Well, I tried again with another new account using a shorter password and got this debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/nugget3/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /Users/nugget3/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 434
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1  CONNECTION CLOSED?

Comment: Well, I tried a THIRD time and again with a really short pw think none of this makes sense. And now it works. So bizarre. Thank you for trying to help me. I have no idea why these other accounts behaved badly. I will leave them in place so that I can troubleshoot them when I learn more.

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem. The remote host logs the origin of each RSA or DSA key. This is seen in plain text at the end of each line in the authorized keys list (which you usually cannot see because `nano` does not text wrap).

I was ssh'ing first to the remote host, *then* copying the key and merging it with `authorized_keys`. Bad.

From the client machine,the key has to be copied to the remote host with that special copy command, `scp`, or `ssh-copy-id` (OS X does not have this one unless installed with `brew` or `port`).

Then the merge to `authorized_keys` can be performed. Careless human error on my part.

Comment: Suffered a copy/paste error as well.  Was able to circumvent it using `cat` locally and `nano` on the server.  Upvoting because sometimes retrying the trivial is the best way to fix a problem.

Comment: "Then the merge to `authorized_keys` can be performed". *facepalm* I thought it was a directory! Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a secondary key to connect to a host.
In order to connect using that, you need to add that to identity using:

```
ssh-add yourPrivateKey
```

Answer (score 0):

I was at my wits end... I was under the mistaken impression `ssh-copy-id` was a Linux-only utility. Finally I just swallowed my pride and typed the command is the macOS Terminal and it worked!

```
ssh-copy-id me@sshd-server
```

I don't know what magic `ssh-copy-id` does, but it just worked. I was able to log in without a password successfully with the simple command:

```
ssh me@sshd-server
```

I had zero luck with `cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_hosts`. Every time I tried ssh'ing to the server it just kept asking me for the passphrase. This is with the correct 600 permission on `authorized_hosts` and 700 on `~/.ssh`.